# Passing a variable from server side to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint

I can't pass the server side variable to my javascript.

In my control

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" runat="server" value="Add"  onclick="javascript:OpenAttachmentUpload('<%=ID%>')" />
```

This is my javascript

```
 function OpenAttachmentUpload(ID) {
        var strPageURL = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Folder/upload.aspx")+"?id=" %>' + ID;
        OpenCustomDialogWithRefresh(strPageURL, 350, 200, "Attachment");
    }
```

This is my server side variable

```
    private string ControlSessionId
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["_SessionId"] == null)
                ViewState["_SessionId"] = Guid.NewGuid();
            return ViewState["_SessionId"].ToString();
        }
    }
    public string ID { get { return ControlSessionId; } }
```

Whenever I click the add button, it open upload.aspx but the query string **id** value is `<%=ID%>`.
I would like to get the unique ID key from the server side.

What's wrong with my javascript?
My project is sharepoint project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this in server side.

```
btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OpenAttachmentUpload('" + ID + "')");
```

Comment: Yes, very nice to meet you too bro.

:-)